# SQL Output Y/N comparing date column from different tables

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'd like to output Y or N. If `cc.date1 = T.date` then 'Y'. Or if `cc.date1 < T.date` then 'N'. I'm not quite sure how I can express this in the query below and welcome any suggestions please. The cte is part of a block of a bigger query for a stored procedure. I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 (V10.50) at the moment. Thanks

```
WITH cte_new AS
(
SELECT CC.ID,
CC.col1,
CC.col2,
CC.col3,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CC.ID ORDER BY CC.date1 DESC) AS row_num
FROM table1 AS CC
INNER JOIN #temp AS T 
ON CC.ID = T.ID
WHERE CC.col1 = 'CNT'
AND CC.col2 = 'NEW'
AND CC.date1 = T.date
OR CC.date1 < T.date
)
SELECT *
INTO #NewOld
FROM cte_new
WHERE row_num = 1
```

Comment: FYI, SQL Server 2008 (R2) reached End Of Life last Summer; it's past time you started looking at upgrade paths by now.

Comment: As for the question, have you looked at a [`CASE` expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: Yep, moving to 2016 this month. We are behind but getting there! :)

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for pointing out CASE. I am using that now

Comment: CASE WHEN cc.date1 = t.date THEN 'Y'....something like this

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if the intention of your query is correct.  However, the `WHERE` logic doesn't look correct.  You have:

```
WHERE CC.col1 = 'CNT' AND
      CC.col2 = 'NEW' AND
      CC.date1 = T.date OR
      CC.date1 < T.date
```

I'm pretty sure you intend:

```
WHERE CC.col1 = 'CNT' AND
      CC.col2 = 'NEW' AND
      CC.date1 <= T.date
```

Your version is parsed as:

```
WHERE (CC.col1 = 'CNT' AND CC.col2 = 'NEW' AND CC.date1 = T.date) OR
      CC.date1 < T.date
```